# Closed Form for a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, oeis

I have come across this sequence

$$a_0 = -2, a_1 = 5, a_2 = -28, a_3 = 255$$

and, in general

$$a_n = -\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \binom{2n+4}{2i}a_{n-i} + \binom{2n+4}{2n+1}\bigg)$$

I've tried finding a closed form for it and couldn't. I've also tried plugging it into the OEIS and it didn't return any results. I'm wondering if anyone has seen a sequence like this before or if anyone has any ideas for finding a closed form for it.

Comment: Do you expect this sequence to have a closed form?

Comment: I really don't know what to expect. I would hope it would.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a few more terms above because some might look familiar. Also, is there a limit to the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: It seems that $a_{n+1}/a_n\to+\infty$. Initial terms are -2, 5, -28, 255, 3740, 263172, 20054440, 1976545239, 241711405290, 35938407128470, 6384368521752738, 1335522591566108075, 324932372105125504356, 90977118921843539491715, 29044492832848568056028340, 10487611716068737266804984295, ....